# my connect-flash work in registerProcess but in showForm give me empty array what is this problem?

Tags: javascript

my connect-flash work in registerProcess but in showForm give me empty array what is this problem?

```
showForm(req, res) {
        res.render('./home/auth/register', {
            messages: req.flash('info'),
            recaptcha: this.recaptcha.render()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you put req.flash('info') in the wrong place.
You should try this instead:

```js
showForm(req, res) {
        req.flash('info', 'Your message goes here'),
        res.render('./home/auth/register', {
            recaptcha: this.recaptcha.render()
        })
    }
```

In the above code I put the line req.falsh('info') before rendering the HTML template